# ASP.NET : Tracking Unique page visits/views

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application where View.aspx page will display the details of each products in a shopping cart.The page displays dynamic data(Ex: For each product id,the content will be different).Now i want to track the unique page views of each product.What are the best solutions to approach this problem ? I am already using google analytics.But i wanna custom solution/code for my web app,so that i can know how many hits came for each product

Comment: You can do that with google analytics, but copy/pasting their simple starter code might be insufficient. You should look into their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a Statistical database, and I create a table, that have the product id, and the total views, for each product.

So every time a product is view by a user, I find in the table, this product line-id, and I am updating this values.

I think that is sound and it is simple.

How ever this is the base idea, you can improve it by your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/analytics/ Set up each product with its on URL, or write it in the tracker dynamically. Also this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: URLs also dynaamicly created with the product id at the end of querystring.Edited my question

Comment: read up on the google analytics tracker, or learn how to rewrite urls